# Mongodb lookup not working with deep id

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working with MomgoDb to get results for the following code (in the context of a get request):

```
db.uiRepo.aggregate([ 
            {$match:{ "module.id": req.params.mid } },
            {"$lookup":
                {
                    from: "privileges",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "ui._id",
                    as: "actions"
                }
            }
        ], {}, function(err, views) {
            if (err) res.json({});
            res.json(views);
        })
```

Now, the problem is the $lookup part because when I remove it, the match function works just fine.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: could you also add some sample data from privileges and uiRepo collections?

Comment: Odds are that `"ui._id"` is actually a "string" where as `"_id"` is an `ObjectId`. 9/10 *"My $lookup does not work"* questions are for exactly this reason. If the types do not match, then you get no results

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

Lookup operation is not supported on the version I was using. Upgrading to 3.4 fixed this